# Remove label from material input on focus and when leave focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material input with placeholder. When I focus on field I remove placeholder, but if I leave focus and field is empty I see transform animation, that I want to remove too.
in this image placeholder that has to be when field is empty.

[image]

And in this image I leave focus:

[image]

```
<mat-form-field class="al-subscribe-form-field">
        <input formControlName="email" matInput type="email">
        <mat-placeholder  class="al-placeholder">{{'SHARED.ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL' | translate}}</mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>

.mat-focused .al-placeholder, .mat-form-field-invalid .al-placeholder {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to add `floatLabel='never'`

```js
<mat-form-field floatLabel='never' class="al-subscribe-form-field" >
    ...
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a legacy form field with a placeholder but no label, you will need to specify an empty label to prevent the placeholder from being promoted.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label></mat-label>
  <input placeholder="Just a placeholder">
</mat-form-field>
```

As per official documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Answer (score 0):

```
    .mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .mat-focused .al-subscribe-form-placeholder,
    .mat-form-field-invalid .al-subscribe-form-placeholder {
        display: none!important;
}

<mat-from-field floatLabel="never"></mat-form-field>
```

It solves my problem